# TF Plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing, time-frequency

I want to divide 5 low frequency of EEG data. Here I am using EMD to obtain that. What I want to ask is how we can create a line which will separate each frequency like this picture below. For example, delta is 0-4 Hz, theta 4-8 Hx, alpha is 8-12 Hz, so on.

This picture is TF Plot obtained from EMD

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "divide 5 low frequency"?

Comment: i want to devide it into 5 part, which is Gamma, Beta, Alpha, Theta, Delta.
Look that frequency axis, 0-4 is delta, 4-8 is theta, 8-12 is alpha, 12-40 is beta, and the other is gamma

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what EMD is, but if that is within Matlab, then you can add the lines to this graph like this:

```
x1 = 0;
x2 = 0.5;
y1 = 4;
y2 = 8;
y3 = 12;
y4 = 40;

figure; hold on
plot([x1, x2], [y1, y1])
plot([x1, x2], [y2, y2])
plot([x1, x2], [y3, y3])
plot([x1, x2], [y4, y4])
```

Make sure your graph goes after `figure; hold on` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it